# Azure App Service slow on first request

Tags: java, spring, azure, tomcat, web-config

I have created an API hosted on Azure. The API is built using Java and Spring Framework. Everything works fine, except the first request each morning, which seems to take more than 1 minute to process. I have configured the server to "Always on" but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I know that the bottleneck is the application server, because even a simple http request with no database calls takes at least 1 minute to process. I have used a free-trial billing plan, can this affect the "always on" feature? If not, what is causing this slow load?

Comment: which app service plan are you using to host this API app?

Comment: I'm using the S1 Standard App Service Plan

Answer (score 0):

The `ALWAYS ON` feature can only be enabled when in the Basic or Standard pricing tier. So if you have used a free-trial billing plan, the options for the `always on` feature was disabled. But you can try to continously ping your Azure App Service to keep it alive.

For more information, you can refer to the blog http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request/.

Comment: I'm also interested to understand why the first request is always slow. I am running a Medium instance with "always on" enabled, yet if there is no activity on the API for a bit (I haven't timed it, but even 10 min or so of inactivity), the API takes a good deal of time to respond. It's actually making me nervous to consider going into production with this given the response time.

Comment: In reference to my other comment, the API is sitting in one of the deployment slots. Does that have any effect on how Azure handles these instances and possibly affect their response times?

Comment: 7 years later and this is still relevant issue...

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue, i.e., after some idle time, the application was unloaded and had to be started again, although *Always on* was enabled.

We contacted the Azure App Services Support to solve the issue. In our case, a **permanent redirect from http to https** in `web.config` caused the issue (there seem to be cases where *Always On* will not work with Tomcat web apps in combination with rewrite rules).

The issue could be solved by adding an exemption for `AlwaysOn` for the redirect. Below you'll find the updated `web.config` that was proposed by an Azure Support Engineer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" lockItem="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="AlwaysOn" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```